# Count the number of times a character occurs consecutively in a binary string - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of binary $strings composed of 1s and dashes.

```
1--1-1-111---1--
1--1-11111111-11
1111-11111--1111
```

I'm retrieving this from a txt file to count how many occurrence of consecutive dashes exists in each string. For example, in the first string, there exists a stretch of 3 consecutive dashes occuring once, dash of 2 twice, and a single dash 3 times. In the second string, i have one stretch of 2 consecutive dashes and two occurrence of a single dash.

My desired outcome is to output, or keep in array or hash for further manipulation, the occurrence of consecutive dashes and the frequency in this notation:

```
3-1, 2-2, 1-3
2-1, 1-2
2-1, 1-1
```

I'm using this statement to count the number of occurrences of dashes globally:

```
$dash_freq = (($string =~ tr/-//) + 1);
```

However, i would like to know how the regex would look to count the frequency for consecutive occurrences.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a regular expression. Just write a loop.

Comment: The length of each string can vary signficantly. They are not all the same length.

Comment: And why is that a problem? Just loop over all the characters in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( %hash, @nums );
    $hash{ length $1 }++ while /(-+)/g;
    push @nums, "$_-$hash{$_}" for sort { $b <=> $a } keys %hash;
    print join( ', ', @nums ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
1--1-1-111---1--
1--1-11111111-11
1111-11111--1111
```

Output:

```
3-1, 2-2, 1-2
2-1, 1-2
2-1, 1-1
```

Comment: I was about to comment that the OP's description appears to suggest a count of 3 for the single dash, but your solution confirms that this was simply a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `split` to extract the dash list, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @dash_freq;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @dashes = split /1+/;

    my %freq;
    $freq{length($_)}++ foreach grep { m/-/ } @dashes;

    push @dash_freq, \%freq;
}

print Dumper(\@dash_freq);

__DATA__
1--1-1-111---1--
1--1-11111111-11
1111-11111--1111
---1111-11111--1111
```